# How is web "walled garden" implemented?

Tags: http

I am not sure I am using the terminology correct, but this is what I am wondering,

When an unauthorized user types in "http://my.original.req.com", this user will be redirected to a login website, so that this user can be authorized. After this user logged in, the webpage redirects to this user's original request "http://my.original.req.com" again.

How is this usually implemented in http protocol? Specifically, after the user logged in, how does the user get redirected to the "http://my.original.req.com" again? Where is this user's original request URL"http://my.original.req.com" kept? What happened in between?

Edit:
The reason I asked this is because we are not implementing this on a http server. We are
doing this on a router. So I was more curious to know if there are any standard about it.

Thanks,
Wei

Comment: [WS-Federation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Federation) maybe?

Comment: people, when you down vote, give them a reason. So they learn from it.

Comment: May be a better fix for programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's usually stored in a querystring parameter in the login page.

Comment: Thanks, is there a standard for this?

Comment: No; it's just obvious.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the framework. For example in ASP.NET MVC, when the framework detects that user is trying to access a protected resource, it redirects theuser to login page with the protected resource URL as a query string parameter.

After successful authentication it takes the URL in query string and redirects it there.

**Edit**
It is always a good idea to check the redirect URL before you redirect. ASP.NET MVC makes sure that the return URL is a local URL. Here is how its implemented in ASP.NET MVC.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Validate the user password
        if (await Secrets.Validate(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            string userId = await Logins.GetUserId(IdentityConfig.LocalLoginProvider, model.UserName);
            await SignIn(userId, model.RememberMe);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    return View(model);
}

private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
{
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```